# How to insert Master/Detail record in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables: `Employee`, `Emp_Address` and `Emp_AddressDetail`.

1. `Employee` table is master and `Emp_Address` is detail.
2. `Emp_Address` is master and `Emp_AddressDetail` is detail.

I want to copy all rows from a table to another table.

How can I do it?

Comment: Not able to understand!! whats the exact problem? Do you want to insert all 3 tables data into one? or want to replicate data of these 3 tables into their replica tables and want to know about handling the foreign key references?

Comment: First copy all rows from `Employees` - then those from `Emp_Address` and in the end, those from `Emp_AddressDetail`. You just cannot copy rows from a "child" table as long you don't have the corresponding rows in its "parent" table in place....

Comment: I want to replicate data of these 3 tables into their replica tables and want to know about handling the foreign key references.

Comment: Okay. In that case please share the relation between tables. As I can clearly see Employee is your master table and doesnt have any foriegn key in it. And Emp_Address and Emp_AddressDetail have the refrence on Employee table.
My question here is does Emp_Address and Emp_AddressDetail both have EmpID as foreign key in it? I assume EMP_AddressDetail has one foriegn key of Emp_Address table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you want to insert data from one table to another? If so, you should have a look at the INTO statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.OneTable FROM Production.AnotherTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tables have foreign keys defined, and those foreign key definitions need to be set on the new database, than you need to take a look at the data diagrams, and identify any tables that do not have foreign key columns. In your case the copy order will be `Employee`, `Emp_Address`, `Emp_AddressDetail`

If you do not have explicit SQL Server maintained foreign keys, or if the foreign keys are not set on the target database, you can just copy the data in any order you like.

Note that it's entirely possible to paint yourself into a corner, e.g. if there was field in the Employee table called PrimaryAddress that would be a foreign key to the Emp_Address table.